# Containing jquery.NoConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to contain jQuery and was hoping I could do something like the following:

```
$.noConflict();
 jQuery("#id").click(Alert("Hello World"));
End.noConflict();
```

I can't seem to see information on it anywhere but it would be useful, because we have a shared library over multiple sites, and now were upgrading to newer version over time we would phase out the use of noConflict but for the time being whilst we upgrade the legacy java script is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you need `noConflict()`?

Comment: Yes, we actually have prototype which we are also phasing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write `window.$ = jQuery`.

Comment: okay so we have two master pages, both call a common.min.js. In the newer master page we use jQuery in the old master page we use prototype. Within the common.min.js which is shared I needed a way to section off jquery from the prototype. I am all for not creating multiple files if we can do it all in one :P as long as the files still readable when not minified. On top of that we have put jquery on the same master page as the one that has prototype to phase it out so needed a way for that not to conflict with jquery functions is well.. Its a crazy triangle and a mess which I hope to tidy up.

Comment: @Anicho: I've been through this. I ended up writing code using `jQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)` until I phased out prototype completely.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I feel the need for `noConflict()` I am doing things wrong. The solution has always been (at least for me) to rearrange the order of the .js file imports at the top of the page!

Comment: Agreed but this is all part of the tidy up, we have tons of functions as we rewrite in the latest jquery we will remove noConflict I have about one month to do it :D.